# Concatenate columns based on certain group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe df1 ike this:

```
            Schema                table Name             temp
0           schema1               table1             col1 INT(1,2) NOT NULL
1           schema1               table1             col2 INT(3,2) NOT NULL
2           schema1               table1             col3 SMALLINT(6,2) NULL
3           schema1               table1             col4 SMALLINT(9,2) NULL
4           schema2               table2             col6 CHAR(20,2) NULL
5           schema2               table2             col7 CHAR(20,4) NULL
6           schema2               table2             col8 CHAR(6,5) NULL
7           schema2               table2             col9 CHAR(6,3) NULL
```

In this dataframe I have two different schemas and tables(`table1` and `table2`). I want to build `create table` statement out of this.

So, from the above dataframe I need a new dataframe which will have 2 rows (since 2 different tables in df1 ) and the value would be

```
df2:

    ddl_statement
0   create table schema1.table1 (col1 INT(1,2) NOT NULL,col2 INT(3,2) NOT NULL,col3_Nbr SMALLINT(6,2) NULL,col4 SMALLINT(9,2) NULL)

1   create table schema2.ITEM_DESC2 (col6 CHAR(20,2) NULL,col7 CHAR(20,4) NULL,Col8 CHAR(6,5) NULL,col9 CHAR(6,3) NULL)
```

How can I achieve this with out using loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and f-strings:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Database/Schema Name', 'entity Name'])['temp'] \
        .apply(lambda x: f"create table {x.name[0]}.{x.name[1]} ({', '.join(x)})") \
        .reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('ddl_statement')
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
                                                                                                                                                  ddl_statement
0  create table schema1.ITEM_DESC1 (Item_Nbr INT(1,2) NOT NULL, Old_Nbr INT(3,2) NOT NULL, Order_Dept_Nbr SMALLINT(6,2) NULL, Acct_Dept_Nbr SMALLINT(9,2) NULL)
1           create table schema2.ITEM_DESC2 (Primary_Desc CHAR(20,2) NULL, Secondary_Desc CHAR(20,4) NULL, Color_Desc CHAR(6,5) NULL, Size_Desc CHAR(6,3) NULL)
```